# Docker Remote API Use case?

Tags: docker

What are the benefits of Docker Remote API versus Docker through Shell in a development environment and CI/CD ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the usage of both tools.

Docker command line's main purpose is user iteration. I wouldn't build a web application which connects to my terminal and performs shell commands.

In another hand, Docker Remote API is intended to those applications. That's what it'a called API anyways. You would perform a curl in your terminal to get your list of images.